# 5 Column layout with 2 gridsplitters - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a 5 column layout. The aim is to have 3 main columns, (left, middle, right) which I could then expand and shrink. To achieve this I added two extra columns which contains the splitters. One between the left and middle column and another between middle and right.

After starting the application and moving the first spliter towards the left the last column (right) suddenly snaps all the way to the left, collapsing all three columns. Any suggestions? Thanks

Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ThreeColumns.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="725">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Left side" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter Background="blue" Width="5" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"></GridSplitter>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Middle" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter Background="blue" Width="5" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="3"></GridSplitter>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Right side" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I managed to solve it by setting the first and last columns width to "auto" and the middle content column to "*":

```
<Window x:Class="ThreeColumns.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="725">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50"  Width="auto" Name="Col1"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7" Name="Col2"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Name="Col3" Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="7" Name="Col4"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="50" Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10" Margin="2 2 2 2">
                <TextBlock Text="Left side" Width="250" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
            </Border>

            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10" Margin="2 2 2 2">
                <TextBlock Text="Middle" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10" Margin="2 2 2 2">
                <TextBlock Text="Right side" Width="250" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <GridSplitter Background="blue" Width="5" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" ResizeDirection="Columns"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ZIndex="1"/>
            <GridSplitter Background="blue" Width="5" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" ResizeDirection="Columns"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ZIndex="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Funny I pasted your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Blam it is stranged I tried it on different machines and was getting the same results. With some help from your previous post (which I think you deleted) I managed to get it working, I updated my post. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me.
But I find it cleaner to use fixed width for the splitter and center it.
It the splitter is against the next column sometimes it seems to wack out.

Often need to use Auto for all but one.
If you try something like 2* 3* for relative sizing things often go bad.
If you want even sizing to start sometimes multiple single * will work.

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="7"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Left side" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter Background="blue" Width="3" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1"></GridSplitter>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Middle" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <GridSplitter Background="blue" Width="3" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="3"></GridSplitter>
        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="10">
            <TextBlock Text="Right side" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It's strange , just tried this code and get the same behaviour. If I slide the first splitter to the left all of a sudden all three colums collapse to the left.

Comment: @rauland Then go with Auto on the outer.   Once it get past two columns sizing it get tricky.   I have resorted to only two at a time where I put a grid in the column to build them up.